# TestFlight build is not working same for every user

Tags: ios, react-native, testflight

I'm new to iOS development.
I have a app built with React Native and already deployed on app store. I'm working on version 2.0 of the app. Previous version was built by some other developer company.
They delivered the source code for the version one, I'm gonna work on top of the codes of version one.

I've pushed a build on TestFlight to check if the existing codes are okay.

Now on **TestFlight,**
most of the testers are not finding any problems but **some users can't login.** Whenever they try to login, either there is an infinite loading screen or the app takes back to splash screen. The users then tries again to login but again after entering otp, user is sent back to splash screen.

Now this scenario is happening **only with 2, out of our 20+ testers.** We don't know where the problem is because we can't recreate the same issue in other devices.

**Also, this same app with same code is deployed on google play store and working without any issue.**

Has anyone else faced similar issue? Is it a problem with the test flight?

N.B: Everyone using iphone with latest iOS update 16.3

Answer (score 0):

Try to log in with their credentials on your simulator/local device where you have access to logs etc.
Sounds to me like there's an issue with some specific accounts, maybe they have some properties in their accounts that has been altered/removed that's making the login process fail / load the correct content.

Edit: If there's infinite loading, have they checked their internet connectivity as well?

Comment: Tried these already. They have steady internet connection. And as the version 1.0 is already in the app store, that's working fine. This problem is only seen in the build in TestFlight. And only in those 2 devices. Even they tried to login with different accounts too, same problem occurs. Never saw such weird problem.